# Is there a css/javascript property for when a div is selected in the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example, if I have the URL `example.com/#foo`, then styling is applied to the div `foo`. If this does not exist in pure css, what is an efficient and reliable way to do it in javascript/jquery?

Comment: Use JavaScript to get the hash, find the div with the hash, then apply a style to the matched div. Many solutions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JavaScript needed. Use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) css selector.

```css
:target {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  foo
</div>
<div id="bar">
  bar
</div>
<a href="#foo">link to #foo</a>
<br>
<a href="#bar">link to #bar</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the hash using `window.location.hash`

*Assuming the div has an `id = hash`.*

**JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById(window.location.hash);
if (div) {
  div.style.... = ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#' + window.location.hash).css({...})
```